# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.summary.summary' has no attribute 'histogram'

Tags: python, image, tensorflow

I'm following the "[TensorFlow for Poets](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#4)" tutorial, and I'm stuck at the image retraining, when I try to run this command:

```
sudo python3 tensorflow/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py 
--bottleneck_dir=/tf_files/bottlenecks 
--how_many_training_steps 500 
--model_dir=/tf_files/inception --output_graph=/tf_files/retrained_graph.pb 
--output_labels=/tf_files/retrained_labels.txt 
--image_dir tf_files/flower_photos
```

and it seems like working fine, like

```
Creating bottleneck at /tf_files/bottlenecks/roses/5960270643_1b8a94822e_m.jpg.txt
Creating bottleneck at /tf_files/bottlenecks/roses/8032328803_30afac8b07_m.jpg.txt
Creating bottleneck at /tf_files/bottlenecks/roses/14176042519_5792b37555.jpg.txt
...
```

but at last, I got an Error,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "tensorflow/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py", line 1014, in <module>
tf.app.run()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 30, in run
sys.exit(main(sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
File "tensorflow/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py", line 789, in main
bottleneck_tensor)
File "tensorflow/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py", line 698, in add_final_training_ops
variable_summaries(layer_weights)
File "tensorflow/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py", line 660, in variable_summaries
tf.summary.histogram('histogram', var)

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.summary.summary' has no attribute 'histogram'
```

I'm using TensorFlow on linux, and I didn't install Docker as it isn't necessary. I don't know how to fix this because I'm a beginner. Please help me..

Comment: Do you have the right tensorflow version ?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, the problem is that you are calling an attribute that is not present on the objet `tensorflow.python.summary.summay`. Run `dir(tensorflow.python.summary.summay)`to get a list with all the methods and attributes of the object, since it may have gotten its name changed in new versions.

Also test you are using the correct class for this (since `summary.summary` seems pretty odd to me)

Comment: yeah, tf.histogram_summary is also added, tf.histogram_summary(tag, values, collections=None, name=None).....https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/train.html#summary-operations

Comment: Umm.. I don't understand well what you are talking cause I am very biginner.. so what should I do if there is problem?

Answer (score -1):

Seems to be a bug in the early version.Update the tensorflow python package (sudo pip install tensorflow --upgrade).